# Jclouds - Specify a network interface when assigning floating IP

Tags: ip, openstack, jclouds

I was able to create an instance in Openstack specifying multiple networks. Instance has two network interfaces and each is assigned a private IP as  expected. Additionally I was able to assign a floating IP successfully.
The floating IP is always assigned to the first interface eth0. What I want to know is how to specify a a network interface of my choice to which the floating IP is assigned.

I noticed that portUuid can be specified in nova NetworkInterface. But my issue is how to get the portUuId of the network interface I want?

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can use jclouds Neutron to list existing ports and then get their uuids (it should be the port id).

```
PortApi api = neutronApi.getPortApi("region");
List<Port> ports = api.list().concat().toList();
ports.get(0).getId(); // Returns the uuid of the first port.
```

You can get neutron with this maven dependency:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.jclouds.labs</groupId>
  <artifactId>openstack-neutron</artifactId>
  <version>1.8.0</version>
</dependency>
```